# Why does calling np.array() on this list comprehension produce a 3d array instead of 2d?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a script produces the first several iterations of a Markov matrix multiplying a given set of input values. With the matrix stored as `A` and the start values in the column `u0`, I use this list comprehension to store the output in an array:

```
out = np.array([ ( (A**n) * u0).T for n in range(10) ])
```

The output has shape `(10,1,6)`, but I want the output in shape `(10,6)` instead. Obviously, I can fix this with `.reshape()`, but is there a way to avoid creating the extra dimension in the first place, perhaps by simplifying the list comprehension or the inputs?

Here's the full script and output:

```
import numpy as np

# Random 6x6 Markov matrix
n = 6
A = np.matrix([ (lambda x: x/x.sum())(np.random.rand(n)) for _ in range(n)]).T
print(A)

#[[0.27457312 0.20195133 0.14400801 0.00814027 0.06026188 0.23540134]
# [0.21526648 0.17900277 0.35145882 0.30817386 0.15703758 0.21069114]
# [0.02100412 0.05916883 0.18309142 0.02149681 0.22214047 0.15257011]
# [0.17032696 0.11144443 0.01364982 0.31337906 0.25752732 0.1037133 ]
# [0.03081507 0.2343255  0.2902935  0.02720764 0.00895182 0.21920371]
# [0.28801424 0.21410713 0.01749843 0.32160236 0.29408092 0.07842041]]

# Random start values
u0 = np.matrix(np.random.randint(51, size=n)).T
print(u0)

#[[31]
# [49]
# [44]
# [29]
# [10]
# [ 0]]

# Find the first 10 iterations of the Markov process
out = np.array([ ( (A**n) * u0).T for n in range(10) ])
print(out)

#[[[31.         49.         44.         29.         10.
#    0.        ]]
#
# [[25.58242101 41.41600236 14.45123543 23.00477134 26.08867045
#   32.45689942]]
#
# [[26.86917065 36.02438292 16.87560159 26.46418685 22.66236879
#   34.10428921]]
#
# [[26.69224394 37.06346073 16.59208202 26.48817955 22.56696872
#   33.59706504]]
#
# [[26.68772374 36.99727159 16.49987315 26.5003184  22.61130862
#   33.7035045 ]]
#
# [[26.68766363 36.98517264 16.50532933 26.51717543 22.592951
#   33.71170797]]
#
# [[26.68695152 36.98895204 16.50314718 26.51729716 22.59379049
#   33.70986161]]
#
# [[26.68682195 36.98848867 16.50286371 26.51763013 22.59362679
#   33.71056876]]
#
# [[26.68681128 36.98850409 16.50286036 26.51768807 22.59359453
#   33.71054167]]
#
# [[26.68680313 36.98851046 16.50285038 26.51769497 22.59359219
#   33.71054886]]]

print(out.shape)

#(10, 1, 6)

out = out.reshape(10,n)
print(out)

#[[31.         49.         44.         29.         10.          0.        ]
# [25.58242101 41.41600236 14.45123543 23.00477134 26.08867045 32.45689942]
# [26.86917065 36.02438292 16.87560159 26.46418685 22.66236879 34.10428921]
# [26.69224394 37.06346073 16.59208202 26.48817955 22.56696872 33.59706504]
# [26.68772374 36.99727159 16.49987315 26.5003184  22.61130862 33.7035045 ]
# [26.68766363 36.98517264 16.50532933 26.51717543 22.592951   33.71170797]
# [26.68695152 36.98895204 16.50314718 26.51729716 22.59379049 33.70986161]
# [26.68682195 36.98848867 16.50286371 26.51763013 22.59362679 33.71056876]
# [26.68681128 36.98850409 16.50286036 26.51768807 22.59359453 33.71054167]
# [26.68680313 36.98851046 16.50285038 26.51769497 22.59359219 33.71054886]]
```

Comment: It’s probably not the cause of the problem, but numpy matrices are being phased out in favour of normal ndarrays. See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html. Can you try replacing the matrix and see if that changes anything? I think you could also make better use of broadcasting, although I do not have access to a computer to check.

Comment: Huh. You are correct, it works just fine if I use arrays all the way, although I have to admit I find the ```np.linalg.matrix_power(A,n)``` notation clunky.

Comment: Wonderful! I’ll take a look at the rest of the code tomorrow, to try to see if there are other improvements that can be made :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to go ahead and post the corrected code as an answer.

Comment: `A` is (6,6), `u0` is (6,1); their `@` is (6,1); transposed (1,6); stacking 10 produces (10,1,6).  If `u0` is (6,) array, the `@` is (1,6) matriix  (np.matrix forces it to be 2d).

Comment: `np.vstack` will combine the (1,6) matrices on the first dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj would you mind taking a look at the answer I posted? I tried to implement the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion lies with how arrays can be joined.

Start with a simple 1d array  (in `numpy` 1d is a real thing, not just a 'row vector' or 'column vector'):

```
In [288]: arr = np.arange(6)                                                    
In [289]: arr                                                                   
Out[289]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

`np.array` joins element arrays along a new 1st dimension:

```
In [290]: np.array([arr,arr])                                                   
Out[290]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

`np.stack` with the default axis value does the same thing.  Read its docs.

We can make a 2d array, a column vector:

```
In [291]: arr1 = arr[:,None]                                                    
In [292]: arr1                                                                  
Out[292]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
In [293]: arr1.shape                                                            
Out[293]: (6, 1)
```

Using `np.array` on its transpose the (1,6) arrays:

```
In [294]: np.array([arr1.T, arr1.T])                                            
Out[294]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])
In [295]: _.shape                                                               
Out[295]: (2, 1, 6)
```

Note the middle size 1 dimension, that bothered you.

`np.vstack` joins the arrays along the existing 1st dimension.  It does not add one:

```
In [296]: np.vstack([arr1.T, arr1.T])                                           
Out[296]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Or we could join the arrays horizontally, on the 2nd dimension:

```
In [297]: np.hstack([arr1, arr1])                                               
Out[297]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```

That is (6,2) which can be transposed to (2,6):

```
In [298]: np.hstack([arr1, arr1]).T                                             
Out[298]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you put into coming up with these examples. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `np.array()` for input and `@` for matrix multiplication, it works as expected.

```
# Random 6x6 Markov matrix
n = 6
A = np.array([ (lambda x: x/x.sum())(np.random.rand(n)) for _ in range(n)]).T

# Random start values
u0 = np.random.randint(51, size=n).T

# Find the first 10 iterations of the Markov process
out = np.array([ ( np.linalg.matrix_power(A,n) @ u0).T for n in range(10) ])
print(out)

#[[29.         24.          5.         12.         10.         32.        ]
# [15.82875119 13.53436868 20.61648725 19.22478172 20.34082205 22.45478912]
# [21.82434718 10.06037119 14.29281935 20.75271393 18.76134538 26.30840297]
# [20.77484848 10.1379821  15.47488423 19.4965479  20.05618311 26.05955418]
# [21.02944236 10.09401438 15.24263478 19.48662616 19.95767996 26.18960236]
# [20.96887722 10.11647819 15.30729334 19.44261102 20.00089222 26.16384802]
# [20.98086362 10.11522779 15.29529799 19.44899285 19.99137187 26.16824587]
# [20.97795615 10.11606978 15.29817734 19.44798612 19.99293494 26.16687566]
# [20.97858032 10.11591954 15.29752865 19.44839852 19.99245389 26.16711909]
# [20.97844343 10.11594666 15.29766432 19.4483417  19.99254284 26.16706104]]
```

Comment: Here `A` is (6,6) array, `u0` is (6,) (the transpose does nothing).  The `@` is then (6,).  Again the transpose is not needed.

Comment: If the transpose does nothing, how would I go about getting ```A * (the row u0)``` (resulting in a 6 by 6 array), as I am accustomed to doing when I have them stored as matrices? In linear algebra, I'm used to having vectors as columns. (To be clear, that's not needed for this exact problem, but it will arise in other contexts as I transition from using matrices to ndarrays.)

Comment: Look at how `matmul` handles 1d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to the code, although I'm not 100% certain that the result is still the same (I am not familiar with Markov chains).

```py
import numpy as np

n = 6

num_proc_iters = 10

rand_nums_arr = np.random.random_sample((n, n))
rand_nums_arr = np.transpose(rand_nums_arr / rand_nums_arr.sum(axis=1))

u0 = np.random.randint(51, size=n)

res_arr = np.concatenate([np.linalg.matrix_power(rand_nums_arr, curr) @ u0 for curr in range(num_proc_iters)])
```

I would love to hear if anyone can think of any further improvements.

Comment: This looks nice to me. I wonder if anyone can weigh in on using array casting and concatenation instead of list comprehensions. I find the latter more intuitive, but is there a stylistic or performance reason to favor the former?

Comment: What do you mean by "array casting"? I actually kept the list comprehension in `res_arr`, but I am looking for a better (pure numpy) way of doing it.

Comment: I'm referring to your 5th nonblank line, ```np.transpose(rand_nums_arr / rand_nums_arr.sum(axis=1))```. You normalize along the rows of the array instead of first creating the normalized rows and then putting them in an array.

Comment: @Max ah yes, I find it much easier to understand. Performance is probably better too.

Comment: I was able to consolidate this even further by eliminating the transpositions. I've submitted it as an edit to your post since it won't fit in a comment.

Comment: @Max Wonderful! Sadly I can’t see anything, I believe I don’t have enough reputation for that. Oh well, i’ll have to wait until it gets approved :)